Resynthesising a Clifford from a $CNOT +T$ circuit and a Pauli string
I'm implementing something which requires generating a Clifford circuit for the unitary transformation $C$.
$$
C = U \, P \, U^\dagger
$$
Here $U$ is an $n$ qubit circuit containing only $CNOT$ and $T$ gates. $P$ is a Pauli string of length $n$. I want a constructive method to synthesise a circuit implementing $C$ given $U$ and $P$ with no non-Clifford gates.
I've been thinking of $U$ as a phase polynomial circuit. A phase polynomial is a unitary operation which transforms a state $|x\rangle$ as follows...
$$
|x\rangle \mapsto e^{2 \pi i p(x)}|g(x)\rangle
$$
Where $g$ is a linear reversible function and $p(x)$ is a linear combination of Boolean functions $f_i$. Its known that we can implement any phase polynomial with the $\{CNOT, Rz\}$ gateset. So a $CNOT$+ $S$ + $T$ circuit $U$ can be thought of as a phase polynomial where all of the $Z$ rotations are some integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{4}$.
Now phase polynomials are "Hadamard-free" and can be implemented as a diagonal operator $D$ followed by a linear reversible circuit $L$. So I think its the case that $U = D L$.
We now have
$$
\begin{align}
C &= U\, P\, U^\dagger \\
  &= D\, L\, P\, L^\dagger D^\dagger \\
  &= D \, P'\, D^\dagger \\
  &= P' \, D' \, D^\dagger \\
C &= P' \, Q
\end{align}
$$
Here $P' = L \, P \, L^\dagger$ and $Q = D' \, D^\dagger$.
We know that $P'$ is a Pauli string as $L$ can be implemented with only $CNOT$ gates ($CNOT$ is Clifford) and conjugating $P$ by a Clifford yields another Pauli string.
I pull $P'$ to the front here. I do this by considering $D$ as a sequence of diagonal Pauli rotations. If $P'$ anti-commutes with a Pauli string $S_i$, then I can negate the angle of rotation for the string $S_i$.
My question boils down to... Is $Q$ a Clifford operator? I strongly suspect that it is but I'm not sure I have a proper proof of this yet.
I think it can be argued that $Q$ is Clifford by considering $D'$ and $D^\dagger$ as sequences of $\{Z, I\}$ Pauli rotations by some angle $\theta_i$. I think its the case that the angles of rotation in $D'$ and $D^\dagger$ will either combine to $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ or cancel to zero but I'm not totally confident in my algebra.

This works out mostly following the way I described. This wasn't working out for me at first but that was due to a bug in my code.
Firstly note that any diagonal unitary $D$ can be implemented as a sequence of exponentiated Pauli strings $S_j$ from $\{ Z, I\}$ and some rotation angles $\theta_j$.
$$
D = \exp\Big( \frac{i}{2} \sum_j \theta_j\, S_j\Big)
$$
In our case $D$ is a diagonal $CNOT + T$ circuit so we have
$$
D: \Big\{\big(S_0, \,\frac{k_0\pi}{4}\big)\,, ...\,, \big(S_j, \,\frac{k_j \pi}{4}\big) \Big\}
$$
Here the $k_j$ terms are integers. Our circuit is non-Clifford for $k$ values of $\pm 1$ which correspond to $T$ and $T^\dagger$ gates.
Given that all of the strings are tensor products of $Z$ and $I$ Paulis we know that these mutually commute with one another.
For $D^\dagger$ we just negate the angles. Note that $Z$ and $I$ are self-adjoint.
$$
D^\dagger: \Big\{\big(S_0, \,-\frac{k_0\pi}{4}\big)\,, ...\,, \big(S_j, \,-\frac{k_j \pi}{4}\big) \Big\}
$$
Now we obtain $D'$ from commuting the Pauli string $P'$ to the front of the circuit.
Lets define the indicator function $\eta(A, B)$.
$$
\eta(A, B) =\begin{cases}
0\,, \quad [A, \,B] = 0\\
1\,, \quad \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
So to construct $D'$ we negate the coefficents whenever the corresponding string does not commute with $P'$.
$$
D':  \Big\{\big(S_0, \,(-1)^{\eta(S_0, \, P')}\frac{k_0\pi}{4}\big)\,, \,...\,, \big(S_j, \,(-1)^{\eta(S_j, \, P')}\frac{k_j \pi}{4}\big) \Big\}
$$
Finally combining $D'$ with $D^\dagger$ to get $Q$ our Pauli strings will have the coefficents
$$
\theta_j = \frac{k_j \pi}{4}\Big( (-1)^{\eta(S_j, \,P')  } - 1\Big)
$$
Now observe that if $P'$ does not commute with $S_j$ the angle $\theta_j$ will be $-\frac{k_j\pi}{2}$ which is Clifford. If $S_j$ and $P'$ do commute then the rotation angle will be equal to $0$. Either way the sequence of Pauli exponentials implementing $Q$ must have Clifford angles.
